# I want to be a maths teacher

Tags: reference-request

Hi I am 53yrs old and want to become a math's teacher. I will literally have to start from scratch as I have standard 8 math's high school which you can imagine is a long time ago, 1979. But I am very keen, excited and committed to this dream. Where would I start. I am financially secure so will be able to study full time. I would want to teach math's to school pupils from Junior to high school and possibly go into private tutoring. If someone could guide me on where I will start and end to be able to become proficient as a math's teacher I would be grateful for the help. Andre

Comment: Good luck! $\;\;\;$

Comment: Forgive me asking this, but I have to: how proficient in math are you? Please, take no offence, I'm far for suggesting [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/444882/26306), but because of the [Dunning–Kruger effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect), one have to wonder...

Answer (score 1):

Having NOT read it, I am tempted to suggest [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000W18X5Q) by Y. Perelman! I did however read his book on Physics when I was around the same age as your intended audience. And, it did make me excited about science :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the UK there are broadly two routes: undergraduate and postgraduate.

**Undergraduate**

This is quite rare. You will take a degree in education. You'll spend three or four years learning about maths, education and being on placements in schools.

**Graduate**

This is the most common and most prestigious route. You must be a university graduate. Although your degree does not have to be in Mathematics, most schools ask for Mathematics graduates in their job adverts.

If you have a degree in Mathematical subjects (Maths, Physics, Economics, etc.) then you'll have to pass numeracy and literacy tests before you're allowed on to a teacher training program. If you have a degree in another subject then you'll have to take a one year Maths Enhancement course. If you pass that then you can sit the literacy and numeracy tests to get on a teacher training program. Of course, there's no automatic place on a teacher training course; you'll need to apply and be interviewed.

Then you spend a year training. You'll have to go to lectures on educational psychology and philosophy as well as write essays on topics such as learning disabilities, etc. you'll also have placements in schools where you'll start by watching teachers teach. That will build up to you teaching a reduced timetable yourself. At the end of the course, you'll need to have evidence that you have met all of the governments standard to be given newly qualified teacher status.

Next, you'll need to find a job. This is much easier said than done.

When you have a job, you'll be under government review for another year where you have to be observed six times and have a mentor rate your performance and report on your progress. If all goes well they'll recommend you for qualified teacher status.